# Get Office 365 users with a specific domain via Powershell

Tags: powershell, office365

I am looking for a way to export a list of users from our Office 365 tenant.

I have tried like below :

```
Get-MSOLUser -All | Where-Object {$_.IsLicensed -eq $true -and $_.BlockCredential -eq $false} | Select-Object  FirstName, LastName, UserPrincipalName, @{Name=’Licenses’;Expression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.Licenses))} -Expand Proxyaddresses | ? {$_ -cmatch '^SMTP\:.*@domain.onmicrosoft.com'} | Export-Csv C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Userlist.csv
```

Output :

```
#TYPE System.String
"FirstName","LastName","UserPrincipalName","Licenses","Length"
"mailbox2",,"mailbox2@domain.onmicrosoft.com","Microsoft.Online.Administration.UserLicense","48"
```

My desired output :

```
"FirstName","LastName","UserPrincipalName","Licenses","Proxyaddresses"
"mailbox",,"mailbox@domain.onmicrosoft.com","aksigorta365:STANDARDPACK","mailbox2@domain.onmicrosoft.com"
```

Comment: What isn't working for you?

Comment: I am getting incorrect output. I have updated my question.